# AWS DynamoDB Encryption

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to encrypt a column lets say "Password" in AWS DynamoDB. After inserting the value in that field it shows that field as it is without encrytpion. The setting is default means the key is AWS Owned. What should i do to make it an encrypted field.

Comment: Where do see the field? In the AWS console encryption is mostly hidden in a sense that you see the decrypted value as long as you have access to the key. Are you using server-side encryption or client-side encryption? Who do you want to protect the password from? Why do *encrypt* passwords in the first place instead of hashing them?

Comment: I wanted this to be done on the server side. Also, I have already hashed the field. 
Now i want to insert some field in a format which we can't understand.
I have already tried various methods to achieve what i want now (have tried secrets manager and RDS proxy for the connecting with other server or services and securing it)
trying something new and not sure how to do encrypt or hash in such a way that we can't understand and also have to decrypt the same using a lambda function.

Comment: That is still too broad, you are not providing any valuable details, why do you want to encrypt something, using what service, why does the existing encryption not suffice, etc....

Comment: the issue is i'm facing latency issue when trying to connect with the RDS server using secrets manager services. To remove this i have implemented 
1. RDS proxy works fine and reverting this change i have tried below
2.VPC and making connection global both works fine reduce the connection time to 1/4th .
Now there is 3rd approach is in my mind that storing the credentials in the dynamodb in encrypted or in a form that humans can't read and then establish the connection but encryption can be done at rest only and HASH means partition only(correct me if i'm wrong). How can i encrypt at server

Answer (score 1):

First of all: DynamoDB encrypts your Data at REST (like the most databases do). This just means that, if everyone would go to a AWS data center and tears out a drive, the data stored on this drive would be encrypted and not usable.

But in your use-case you mentioned a password. In general, passwords should never be stored in encrypted but hashed. You choose an algorithm that provides resistance against [ASICs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit) and [salt your inputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)). I would suggest [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2), which seems to be the best choice to me at the moment (I'm not a Crypto-Expert!).

If you really need to protect data not only at rest, you should encrypt the data on client-side and just store the encrypted data. Be aware that indexing and sorting encrypted data is opposite to the confidentially you embrace through encryption.

Comment: I wanted this to be done on the server side. Also, I have already hashed the field. 
Now i want to insert some field in a format which we can't understand.
I have already tried various methods to achieve what i want now (have tried secrets manager and RDS proxy for the connecting with other server or services and securing it)
trying something new and not sure how to do encrypt or hash in such a way that we can't understand and also have to decrypt the same using a lambda function.